# SQLPLUS: SELECT INTO prompting for variable value

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, sqlplus

Any idea why this is prompting me for the value?  I'm calling the script via batch file:

```
DECLARE
   precount   NUMBER;
   nowcount   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO precount FROM PLAN_OFFER_BK_PRE_SCRIPT WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nowcount FROM PLAN_OFFER WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';
END;
/

-- NUMBER OF MEC/MVP RECORDS
SPOOL logs\MVP_MEC_UPDATED.log APPEND
PROMPT &&CLIENTID   &&precount  &&nowcount
SPOOL OFF;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersand character (`&`) prompts for values before execution time by default. That is not how you display values of variables. Try the below instead.

```
set serveroutput on

SPOOL logs\MVP_MEC_UPDATED.log APPEND
DECLARE
   precount   NUMBER;
   nowcount   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO precount FROM PLAN_OFFER_BK_PRE_SCRIPT WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nowcount FROM PLAN_OFFER WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';

    dbms_output.put_line('precount: ' || precount || ',  nowcount:' || nowcount );
END;
/

SPOOL OFF
```

Passing a variable to a script in SQL*Plus. The script, let's say, `1.sql`:

```
set serveroutput on feedback off verify off
define CLIENTID=&1

SPOOL logs\MVP_MEC_UPDATED.log APPEND
DECLARE
   precount   NUMBER;
   nowcount   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO precount FROM PLAN_OFFER_BK_PRE_SCRIPT WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nowcount FROM PLAN_OFFER WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';

    dbms_output.put_line('CLIENTID: ' || '&CLIENTID' || ', precount: ' || precount || ',  nowcount:' || nowcount );
END;
/

SPOOL OFF
exit
```

Invoking it:

```
sqlplus -s user/password @1.sql 101
```

Where 101 is the `CLIENTID`. Or:

```
sqlplus -s user/password @1.sql %CLIENTID%
```

Where `%CLIENTID%` is a variable in your batch script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you prompted for &&CLIENTID &&precount and &&nowcount?

I believe that's where your problem comes from.

If you want to display the results for precount and nowcount, can you try:

set serveroutput on

```
DECLARE
   precount   NUMBER;
   nowcount   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO precount FROM PLAN_OFFER_BK_PRE_SCRIPT WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO nowcount FROM PLAN_OFFER WHERE COV_IN = 'Y' AND PLAN_IN = 'Y';
dbms_output.put_line(precount);
dbms_output.put_line(nowcount);

END;
/
```